# Divs not aligning

Tags: html, css

I have 3 simple divs with some cosmetic styles that are supposed to be aligned in a row, Two of them have images that are on the left and right sides while middle one contains another div containing text.

I am able to fit the image in divs but the middle one that contains text is not aligning horizontally with other two.

Following is the html

```
 <div class="eggpic">
    <img src="smiley.gif"/>
 </div>
 <div class="timersection">
   <div class="timersectiontext">Hello</div>
 </div>
 <div class="buttonpic softboil">
   <img src="smiley.gif"/>
  </div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle link or that http://jsfiddle.net/4bg7uyoj/1/

Please help in aliging all the divs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How  should it be looks like?

Comment: @felipsmartins if you see the jsfiddle then height of middle div and right/left divs are not equal, I want height of the middle one equal to the height of side ones

Comment: when you use percentage height, the height of the parent container needs to be set, and make sure to vertical-align the inline-block http://jsfiddle.net/4bg7uyoj/3/ otherwise, you could do it with table layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use float:left instead of display:inline-block and give the parent div some height.

Comment: Thanks, it is working. But what is the problem with inline-block I don't get it?

Comment: by using inline-block you are treating your div's to behave like characters or words in a line and words start from a baseline. Think of writing the characters 'a' and 'b' on a line, both start from the same baseline below but end at different heights. Same was the case with your 3 divs, the 2nd div had a lower height but all 3 started from the same base position below. I hope the explanation was clear.

Answer (score 1):

are you displaying the divs using display: inline-block; ? If so you could try adding this to all three divs:

vertical-align: middle;

Otherwise wrap all three divs with another div and display the parent as a table

display: table;

Then display all three child divs as table cells and verticall align them:

display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;